# Multiprocessing slower than sequential when processing text word by word

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I need to process a text word by word. Since the sequential program I wrote is very slow I tried to encode it using multiprocessing library. I found that the multiprocessing software is much much slower than the sequential one. Am I missing something in the code while using Pool function?
The do_something function performs lots of fors and ifs.

Sequential code:

```
class Text():
    def do_something(self, word):
        ....
        # Computational heavy code
        ....
        return new_word
....
new_text = []
for sentence in text:
    new_sentence = []
    for word in sentence:
        ....
        new_word = Text().do_something(word)
        new_sentence += new_word
    new_text.append(new_sentence)
print(new_text)
```

Multiprocess code:

```
class Text():
    def do_something(self, word):
        ....
        # Computational heavy code
        ....
        return new_word

    def do_word(self, word):
        ....
        if len(word) > 2:
            return self.do_something(word).split('$')
        else:
            return ['NONE']

    def do_text(self, text):
        new_text = []
        pool = Pool(processes = cpu_count())   

        for sentence in text:
            new_text.append( [item for sublist in pool.map(self.do_word, sentence.split()) for item in sublist if item != 'NONE'] )
        return new_text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ....
    print(Text().text(file))
```

### Edit

As suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos I've tried to implement multithreading instead of multiprocessing. However, running the code below, the machine seems to use only one core (cpu usage is about 25% while I have a 4-core cpu). The speed seems to be the same obtained with the sequential code (which has 25% cpu usage too).

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

class Text():
    def do_something(self, word):
        ....
        # Computational heavy code
        ....
        return new_word

    def do_word(self, word):
        ....
        if len(word) > 2:
            return self.do_something(word).split('$')
        else:
            return ['NONE']

    def do_text(self, text):
        new_text = []
        pool = ThreadPool(processes = cpu_count())   

        for sentence in text:
            new_text.append( [item for sublist in pool.map(self.do_word, sentence.split()) for item in sublist if item != 'NONE'] )
        return new_text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ....
    print(Text().text(file))
```

Comment: Using multiple *processes* will always have a big overhead, both when creating the new processes and due to the required inter-process communication. Libraries that use threads for data parallelism  have a *much* lower overhead. With multiple processes you have to ensure that each work package is big enough to overcome the IPC overhead. A single word is too little data. You could use multiple processes to handle multiple documents though

Comment: Even *threads* have an overhead btw, although it's a *lot* smaller than IPC.

Comment: So your suggestion is to try to apply multiple process on the entire text or to try multithreading on the splitted sentence? Am i right?

Comment: I'm saying it's not magic. Partitioning the data is an important part of data parallelism.  In *every* case, partitioning large abount of data (eg a document) into 8 parts and have one core process each part will be faster than splitting it by word and feeding them one by one to workers/processes/threads.

Comment: As for the threadpool acting like a single thread, well, if the "Computational heavy code" is so light that it finishes before the next word is submitted, only one thread will be active while the other threads will keep waiting for something to process. That's probably what happens with multiple processes too.

Comment: Reading and splitting the text may be *more* expensive than processing the words themselves. That's why you should try processing multiple *files* in parallel. If you have one really big file, try reading and processing chunks instead of individual words.

Comment: BTW that's what people mean when they talk about [coarse-grained parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity_(parallel_computing)#Coarse-grained_parallelism) and [embarassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problems. If you try to parallelize at too fine a level, you pay for a lot of overhead. That's why you need to parallelize at a coarser level. It's easier to parallelize problems where the chunks have few or no dependencies between them. If there are no dependencies (eg independent files), you can use as many cores as you like

Comment: I don't think that the "Computational heavy code" part can be considered light since involves a loop  itherated 1 million times with multiple ifs in it. However, as you suggested, I've tried multithreading with a partitioned text (in chunks). Same results as before, only 25% cpu usage. At this point I don't know if there are some code issues.

Comment: I tired to elaborate the text chunks with the multiprocess libray. CPU works at 100% (25% for each of the 4 cores), and this code beats the others requiring about 1/4 of the time. However only one question remains: why multithreading isn't working that well?